# PHP Advanced Image Resizing, Similar to how iOS Resizes Images

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I need a PHP page that will take an image and resize to how Apple's iOS does it, which is really strange, but I'll be sure to add some examples. What it does it takes the the image, and places the 2 halves of the image on opposite sides, and fills the middle with the 2 pixels that began in the middle, creating a larger image from a smaller one.
Say here's what goes in to the php function:

[image]

And would be outputted by php like this:

[image: large]

I'm not very good with php and GD so I would have no idea how to even start this sort of thing. But the images would need to be resized to 320px in width and the height would stay the same. Thank you so much to anyone who can write this sort of image manipulation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function MagicStretch(&$image,$newwidth)
{
$width=imagesx($image);
$height=imagesy($image);

$halfwidth=round(($width-2)/2);

$new=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$height);
imagecopyresized($new,$image,$halfwidth,0,$halfwidth-1,0,$newwidth-($halfwidth*2),$height,2,$height);
imagecopy($new,$image,0,0,0,0,$halfwidth,$height);
imagecopy($new,$image,$newwidth-$halfwidth,0,$width-$halfwidth,0,$halfwidth,$height);
imagedestroy($image);
return $new;
}

$image = imagecreatefrompng('whatever.png');
$image = MagicStretch($image,320);
imagepng($image,'whatever_new.png');
```

Comment: You, are a php gd god. That worked, exactly as I needed it to work, thank you so much

Comment: Oh and I needed to add
`imagealphablending($new, false);
    imagesavealpha($new, true);`
after where you defined $new so it worked with transparency

Comment: You don't need to set that because it's default on truecolor images, but it doesn't hurt to do so, and it is good practice.

Comment: Really? Transparency didn't convert until I added those lines

Comment: OK, better always do it then. The PHP manual says it's default, but maybe it's lying or you're using an older PHP version.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php default is false for that function

Comment: Ah OK, that would explain it. It's only default true for `imagealphablending`. Good to know.